# matlab animate 2 3d plots in same figure, have hold on one and not the other

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, plot

For my current project in matlab i am modeling the spread of an infection across the globe. the main method i am using for letting the infection jump is pre-set airport locations.  I also  show when the infection spreads from airport to airport by connecting them with animated lines.  The main map is a 3d surf graph set to default 2D view and the lines are graphed using plot3, which is also in the 2D view.

I have everything working except for one problem.  I need to animate both 3D graphs at the same time in the same figure but I need to let hold not be on for the animation of the map while allowing hold to be on for the animation of the lines connecting airports so that all of the paths will still be shown.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: its not very clear to me, but if you have a handle to each graphic object, you could update just the ones you want. It would help if you post your current code (preferably a small example, not the whole thing)

Comment: Code is very long and most of it is necessary to see what is going on so I'm thinking small bits of code won't be too helpful. Basically what I going on is a surf plot that is 51x101x1 in its dimensions that is being animated so that it's colors are changing with every pass of the loop and it has text values that are always changing as well.

Comment: These I want to not have a hold so that they are redisplayed each time. The other thing being graphed in the figure is multiple lines being plotted with plot3. These lines are plotted inside of the dimensions 51,101,4.  With each pass of the main loop a random number of these lines are plotted. I want to be able to just use hold on these lines so that they will always be shown even though everything else is is being refreshed each time. Did this help?

Comment: Im not sure.. I posted an example, see if it applies to your case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give an example of an animation, maybe it'll be of help:

```
figure('Renderer','zbuffer')

%# this is the surface we will be animating
Z = peaks;
hSurf = surf(Z);
axis tight;    %# fix axis limits

%# these are some fixed lines
hLine(1) = line([0 50], [0 50], [-5 5], 'Color','r' ,'LineWidth',4);
hLine(2) = line([40 0], [0 40], [-5 5], 'Color','g' ,'LineWidth',4);

%# some text as well
hTxt = text(10,40,5, '0');

%# iterations
for j = 1:20
    %# animate the Z-coordinates of the surface
    set(hSurf, 'ZData',sin(2*pi*j/20)*Z)

    %# change text
    set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(j))

    %# flush + a small delay
    pause(0.05)
end
```

Note how we save the handle of the graphics objects (surface, text and line) so that we can manipulate them later on.

[image: animation]

Comment: this may work for what I'm trying to do, let me play with it and see if it will work

Comment: do you know of a way to do this where surf is being called in the loop? And animations are done with drawnow? Also Im trying to make the drawings of the lines be animated as well, the only difference between how I want the surf graph and the line graph to act is that the surf is redrawn and re displayed each time while the lines are drawn but are always visible after being drawn.

Comment: Ill send you an email with 2 pictures of basically what I want only with hold on for everything

Comment: @user2299338: I'm not sure if it still matters (you seem to have found a solution that works for you), but i took a look and prepared my own small example based on the screenshots. Here is the code if you are interested: http://pastebin.com/GJ3NvmKc

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it by saving the handles of everything that I did not want to change, always having hold on, then using the delete function to delete the previous version directly before adding the new ones.  I also added uistack so that they would appear in the order I wanted on the screen

Comment: updating the data of an existing graphic handle (like I've shown in my example) is usually faster than redrawing from scratch each iteration. But I guess it would work too :)

Comment: ok thanks for the help! Ill see if i can figure out the updating method and see if it can speed up the day transitioning some.  thanks again

Comment: After alot of changing, I was able to get mine to work with they way you set it up in your answer and I must say works great! thanks again